# Validation error always on first try

Tags: c, validation

So I run my programme and when entering data for a structure on this set of code, I always get an error when I enter 1 as the data I wish to be entered. Although if i enter the same digit again, it seems to work. I have isolated it to be this part of the code as when I comment this out it all works fine!

Anybody able to help?

```
do{
    puts("What is the packet type?");
    if(scanf(" %d", &records[*rCount].type) == 1
        && records[*rCount].type >= 0
        && records[*rCount].type <= 10)
    {
        valid = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        valid = 0;
        getchar();
        puts("\nNot a valid input");
    }
}while(valid!=1);
```

Structure definition:

```
struct packet{ // declare structure for packet creation
    int source;
    int destination;
    int type;
    int port;
    char data[51];
};
```

Comment: How is your strucure defigned?

Comment: Updated with structure

Comment: Note: The space in `" %d"` does not do anything useful here.  `"%d"` consumes leading whitespace anyways.

Comment: You may have leftover data in `stdin` before getting here.

Comment: how would I be able to get rid of that and why would it only stop me entering 1 working?

Comment: Depends, what was you previous `scanf()` and what data was entered?  `int ch = getchar(); printf("\nNot a valid input %d\n", ch);` is a more useful error message.

Comment: You said "always get an error when I enter 1" - I take that to mean "1" followed by "Enter".  Please advise if you are doing something else.

Comment: Seems like it's just white space when the error comes up.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43296/discussion-between-chux-and-user3103598)

Comment: Yes it's when I hit 1 and enter, but if i did it again after the first error message it works fine for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem appears to be an allocation error on `struct packet records`.